# Strange (Caching?) Issue (Bug?) with T-SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

**This issue was resolved by scripting the view as a create, dropping the view, and then recreating the view using the script, so obviously nothing was *wrong* with the view, per se.  However, I am very curious as to what the cause could be...**

I have a created like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Employees_V]
AS
SELECT  cast(right(EmployeeNo,4) as int) as EmployeeID
,*
,cast(0 as bit) AS [IsTerritoryManager]
,cast(0 as bit) AS [IsCoordinator]
FROM    AD.dbo.ADEmployees_V
```

The `AD.dbo.ADEmployees_V` has a lot of different fields, but the relevant fields are `Status` and `ISStatus`, defined in the creation of the view as:

```
,CASE WHEN c.[Status] = 'Active' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Terminated' END AS [Status]
,CASE WHEN c.[Status] = 'Active' OR ad.[AccountStatus] LIKE '%Enabled%' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Terminated' END AS [ISStatus]
```

Today, I added the `ISStatus` column to `AD.dbo.ADEmployees_V` (`Status` was there previously).

After making that change, I did a:

```
SELECT * FROM [Employees_V]
```

Surprisingly, this did not return the proper results.  `ISStatus` did not appear as a column header, and instead of being populated with 0s, `IsTerritoryManager` was populated with the new `ISStatus` values!

I am guessing that this is some sort of caching issue, but I would *love* an explanation of what is going on under the covers.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this is why there is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx and also why it's generally frowned upon to use `select *` in views or stored procedures.

Comment: @dotjoe . . . Inappropriate comment.  The `create view`, which is in the question, does not have a `select *`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sadly, it does (it blends in because it is in the middle).  I am pretty sure that his answer is correct.  I had never seen that occur before.

Comment: @dotjoe . . . My aopologies.  You are correct.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you move the `*` to the very end of the select?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database VIEW does not reflect the data in the underying TABLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013711/database-view-does-not-reflect-the-data-in-the-underying-table)

Answer (score 1):

The view's column list is generated upon CREATE or ALTER.
If you use a `SELECT * FROm table` in your view definition, the view's column list will be populated with `table`'s current field list.

Adding a new column to the table does not change the view definition, that's why you need to recreate it for it to "refresh" it's columns.

Comment: You don't need to recreate it. `sp_refreshview` also works as per @dotjoe's comment on the question.