# Excel query showing different result than SSMS query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2000

I have had an odd error I cannot explain. Basically, I am running a query to my SQL database using excel and am having non-existent data pop up when it comes to a very particular order in my database.

Here is a simple query surrounding this order:

> select * from OR200100 where OR200100.OR20001='0000793605'

Here is the output in EXCEL
[image]

And here is the same output in SQL
[image]

what is happening here? How could the same query generate 2 different results?

Comment: Holy crap, those look like Scala tables.  Are you *sure* the queries are the same?   Is there really only one record in the OR200100 table for that order number?

Comment: anything else modifying that DB other than your code? since you presumably run the two queries at different times, you'd get different results depending on what's happening elsewhere.

Comment: Your SQL result is missing the row with a value of 4 for OR20002 - can you check if it's supposed to be there?

Comment: What *type* of SQL is this?  And how are you getting the output into EXCEL?

Comment: Also: what's up with those brutal table and column names?

Comment: I have run many querys related to this order number 'OR020001' both should be there.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I suspect it's SQL Server 2000, since the company that supports it now won't support 2005+.  As to your second question, I believe it was ported over at some point from an older database structure, but no one bothered to normalize it.  All the tables are in the format [Four-digit table code][Two-digit company code][Two-digit suffix that I forget].  Instead of a "Company" primary key in each table, the system supports multiple "companies", each with their own set of tables.  Fun stuff.

Comment: @RBarryYoung this is a scala database. I'm not sure what you mean by type other than it is TSQL? I am using the ODBC in windows to connect excel.

Comment: This is a long shot, but did you `SET ROWCOUNT 1` in your SSMS window before running the query?

Comment: @Pondlife the query is just how you see it. I have copy and pasted it many times just to make sure

Comment: @Hexxxer Please execute the following query from both Excel and SSMS and show us the results: `select COUNT(*) from OR200100 where OR200100.OR20001='0000793605'`

Comment: @Hexxxer Yes, but in theory it's still possible that you `SET ROWCOUNT 1` previously and forgot to reset it, or set it in the Query Options in SSMS. It would explain why SQL Server only returns one row instead of two. But please execute the `COUNT(*)` query suggested by @RBarryYoung.

Comment: Having come in this morning I started where I left off last week by executing the same queries I had left open. All of a sudden everything was reporting properly.

Answer (score 1):

Run SQL Server Profiler against the database if you can, then compare the output to the sql query that you are running in ssms.

Comment: I can't confirm this until next week, looks like I am locked out of this instances admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it's SQL Server then, that's important because different SQL products can have very different idiosyncrasies and controls.

The next things to check are these:

1. Is `OR200100` a Table or a View?  If it's a view then post it's code.
2. Are you using the same Login/account from both Excel and SSMS?
3. Are you ***sure*** that you are connecting to the same Server and Database?  SSMS tells you what you are connected to, but client apps like Excel do not and it is *very* common for this type of problem to be caused by the app connecting to a Dev or QA version of the database.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013711/database-view-does-not-reflect-the-data-in-the-underying-table/1013758#1013758) for some of the different ways that this can happen:

Comment: OR200100 is a table, they are both the same login and there is only one server and one database to connect to. I am 200% positive

Comment: OK, I would lean towards #3 then.

Comment: best I can tell it is none of these.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a very similar problem, my query was grouping by week numbers.  What I found was that one of the queries had set datefirst 5 set whilst the other didn't.  I guess the key thing here is make sure, if you are using any SET operations in your ssms queries, these are identical to those in the Excel query string.